# Example of ask pattern in akka typed

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to figure out, how the [ask pattern](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/typed/scaladsl/ActorContext.html#ask[Req,Res](target:akka.actor.typed.RecipientRef[Req])(createRequest:akka.actor.typed.ActorRef[Res]=%3EReq)(mapResponse:scala.util.Try[Res]=%3ET)(implicitresponseTimeout:akka.util.Timeout,implicitclassTag:scala.reflect.ClassTag[Res]):Unit) works. In the documentation, it says:

> Perform a single request-response message interaction with another
>   actor, and transform the messages back to the protocol of this actor.
>
> The interaction has a timeout (to avoid a resource leak). If the
>   timeout hits without any response it will be passed as a
>   Failure(java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException) to the mapResponse
>   function (this is the only "normal" way a Failure is passed to the
>   function).
>
> For other messaging patterns with other actors, see
>   ActorContext#messageAdapter.
>
> This method is thread-safe and can be called from other threads than
>   the ordinary actor message processing thread, such as
>   scala.concurrent.Future callbacks.

Could someone please provide an example to get a better understanding of ask pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Ask pattern' is used in the code outside of actors to communicate with actors. Akka will create an actor for you behind the scenes, send a message and wait for reply within timeout. None of this will block your thread because a `Future` result will be returned immediately which is expected to contain response later on. This is needed because actors can only communicate by sending messages and if you are not within an actor you can't receive a message. It's recommended to use 'tell' `!` instead of 'ask' `?` because it's more efficient but sometimes there is no choice so you have to bridge two worlds together with 'ask'.

Look for examples on internet or try to call actors from `main` method to get a feel of it.

Answer (score 2):

When you need interact with another actor and also depend on its response you might use the tell method to send a message and wait for a new response message (fire-and-forget).
Due to the fact that Akka does not have guaranteed delivery, you might wait infinitely if the receiving actor is down.
Ask returns a Future[Response] that is either completed with a successful response or failed with a TimeoutException if there was no response within the specified timeout.
Please see the the [example](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-akka-actors-ask-examples-future-await-timeout-result)

Comment: " Due to the fact that Akka does not have guaranteed delivery, you might wait infinitely if the receiving actor is down."  Or, more likely, due to the response just not being ready, or even a coding bug, the response message was never even sent. Cannot blame everything on the postal service...

Answer (score 1):

The question you asked is related to akka typed and ask pattern API is slightly different to the standard (untyped) akka.

The examples can be found on [akka docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#request-response-with-ask-from-outside-an-actor) and it is replicated here

```
trait CookieCommand {}
case class GiveMeCookies(replyTo: ActorRef[Cookies]) extends CookieCommand
case class Cookies(count: Int)

import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.AskPattern._

// asking someone requires a timeout and a scheduler, if the timeout hits without response
// the ask is failed with a TimeoutException
implicit val timeout: Timeout = 3.seconds
implicit val scheduler = system.scheduler

val result: Future[Cookies] = cookieActorRef.ask(ref => GiveMeCookies(ref))

// the response callback will be executed on this execution context
implicit val ec = system.executionContext

result.onComplete {
  case Success(cookies) => println("Yay, cookies!")
  case Failure(ex)      => println("Boo! didn't get cookies in time.")
}
```